# Add CheckBoxes to asp.net RadTreeView ChildNodes?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, telerik, radtreeview

I'm trying to add checkboxes to all the child nodes of my radtreeview. 
Now I have checkboxes in every node. What I need is something like:

Node 1

Node 11

Node 111 --- x

Node 112 --- x

Node 12

Node 121

Node 1211 --- x

Node 1212 --- x

so.. only the nodes with no childnodes should have checkboxes!

Regards,

Joao Machado

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on what approach you are using when creating your RadTreeView. Are you setting it up declaratively (defining all the nodes yourself) or are you dynamically creating it? Either way you have to take use of the templating feature of the control, just in different ways.

If it's the first case (declarative approach) you can merely define a template right in the markup of your node, as [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx) displays. You can define templates on a per-node basis so each leaf-node could have a unique look and feel.

If you're doing  the later (dynamically creating the RadTreeView) you will have to use a bit of C# or VB.NET coding to get things done. You're still using a template, only defining it programmatically. There's a documentation article which covers this scenario, [found here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-templates-runtime.html), and it should help you with setting up your leaf nodes to be the only nodes with check boxes.

Comment: Hi Carl.. thanks for the reply! I already found the solution for my problem. For the checkboxes it was easier than I thought:                     `protected void RadTreeView2_NodeCreated(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.ParentNode == null) e.Node.Checkable = false;
        else e.Node.ParentNode.Checkable = false;
    }` Later I used the node template to add some label and ComboBox on nodecheck and nodeclick.

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution! :)